# How to autofill form based on the selected 'id' in django

Tags: python, django, ajax, autofill

I have a form like this:
[image]

how to fill the disabled form field based on the selected 'No. Pelayanan'. This 'No.Pelayanan' is a select field, so when i choose (fill the field) it's autofill the form. i'm looking for any reference to how to do this. thank you!

Comment: Make an ajax request to get the data and put it in the correct place using JavaScript.

Comment: any link or reference, so i could read or watch it? i've search but no clue how to do this

Comment: Where is the code that you have tried for this?

Comment: @MohitC sorry, but i 'm just looking for any references on how to do this kind of stuff. so i didnt think i need to show my code

Comment: @triefauzan you are mistaken. Stackoverflow discourages discussion oriented questions. Read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

This can be done via plain javascript or a little more conveniently using jquery. I will proceed with plain javascript.

you can store the corresponding data for your fields in a js variable or call an api based on your requirement and updated fields from there on changing the select field value.

You can use javascripts inputObject.value to set value of an input field as explained [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/set-the-value-of-an-input-field-in-javascript/)

Here is a working example just for your reference on how this can be done

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <title>Document</title>
        <link
            rel="stylesheet"
            href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
            integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2"
            crossorigin="anonymous"
        />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <form>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="emailfield">Email</label>
                    <input
                        type="email"
                        class="form-control"
                        id="emailfield"
                        placeholder="name@example.com"
                        disabled
                    />
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="exampleFormControlSelect1"
                        >Example select</label
                    >
                    <select class="form-control" id="userselect">
                        <option value="1">user 1</option>
                        <option value="2">user 2</option>
                        <option value="3">user 3</option>
                        <option value="4">user 4</option>
                        <option value="5">user 5</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="fn">First Name</label>
                    <input
                        type="text"
                        class="form-control"
                        id="fn"
                        placeholder="firstname"
                        disabled
                    />
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="ln">Last Name</label>
                    <input
                        type="text"
                        class="form-control"
                        id="ln"
                        placeholder="lastname"
                        disabled
                    />
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
        <script
            src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"
            integrity="sha256-QWo7LDvxbWT2tbbQ97B53yJnYU3WhH/C8ycbRAkjPDc="
            crossorigin="anonymous"
        ></script>
        <script
            src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
            integrity="sha384-ho+j7jyWK8fNQe+A12Hb8AhRq26LrZ/JpcUGGOn+Y7RsweNrtN/tE3MoK7ZeZDyx"
            crossorigin="anonymous"
        ></script>
        <script>
            let usersData = [
                {
                    id: 1,
                    email: "u1@gmail.com",
                    fname: "fname-1",
                    lname: "lname-1",
                },
                {
                    id: 2,
                    email: "u2@gmail.com",
                    fname: "fname-2",
                    lname: "lname-2",
                },
                {
                    id: 3,
                    email: "u3@gmail.com",
                    fname: "fname-3",
                    lname: "lname-3",
                },
                {
                    id: 4,
                    email: "u4@gmail.com",
                    fname: "fname-4",
                    lname: "lname-4",
                },
                {
                    id: 5,
                    email: "u5@gmail.com",
                    fname: "fname-5",
                    lname: "lname-5",
                },
            ];
            document.getElementById('userselect').onchange = (e) => {
                let selectedUser = usersData.find(userdata => userdata.id == e.target.value);
                console.log(selectedUser);
                document.getElementById('emailfield').value = selectedUser.email;
                document.getElementById('fn').value = selectedUser.fname;
                document.getElementById('ln').value = selectedUser.lname;
            };
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

*Please ignore css classes used by me if you don't know about bootstrap as they are just for presentation. The other input fields such as dropdowns, textfields, checkboxes can be filled using js in the similary way.*

For more example you can refer [this](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_text_value.asp)

To know how this can done using jquery you can [check this out](https://api.jquery.com/category/forms/)

Comment: thanks for the example and references, i'll check it out!

Comment: @triefauzan don't forget to upvote and accept the answer if you find it helpful. cheers!